# How to access property from models into Django Queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have this model in which I created a property to format DateTimeField. However I can't access/reference it. Tried this so far:

```
class DataForecast(models.Model):
    date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    rainfall_mm_per_10_min = models.FloatField(null=True)
    wl_observed_m = models.FloatField(null=True)
    wl_forecasted_m = models.FloatField(null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.date_time

    @property
    def date_time_formatted(self):
        import datetime
        return self.date_time.strftime('%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p')
```

And while in my views.py:

```
formatted = [dataforecast.date_time_formatted for dataforecast in DataForecast.objects.all()]
getall = DataForecast.objects.all().values_list(formatted, "rainfall_mm_per_10_min", "wl_observed_m","wl_forecasted_m")
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(list(getall),cls=DjangoJSONEncoder), content_type='application/json')
```

It returns an error:

> Exception Value: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: what you need in `getall` variable?

Comment: As you can see, I need to format my `date_time` field as what I did in my model. So, I added property. I want  the value of `date_time` to be formatted in my `getall` query.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing this:

add .values()

```
DataForecast.objects.all().values()
```

will give you a list to iterate through.

Otherwise remember that the output is an object, so use object.key notation to get the values

Comment: Like I'l add `.values` in query? It returns new error: `'dict' object has no attribute 'date_time_formatted'`.

Answer (score 1):

`values/values_list` take optional field arguments only. They  wont  take  query  set  as  arguments.

Set unicode in return value

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.date_time)
```

You can directly do this

```
In [6]: DataForecast.objects.all().values("date_time", "rainfall_mm_per_10_min", "wl_observed_m","wl_forecasted_m")
Out[6]: [{'date_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 27, 6, 5, 36, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'wl_forecasted_m': 2.0, 'rainfall_mm_per_10_min': 1.0, 'wl_observed_m': 2.0}, {'date_time': datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'wl_forecasted_m': None, 'rainfall_mm_per_10_min': None, 'wl_observed_m': None}]
```

or better try

```
In [7]: DataForecast.objects.all().values()
Out[7]: [{'wl_observed_m': 2.0, 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 27, 6, 5, 36, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'wl_forecasted_m': 2.0, u'id': 5, 'rainfall_mm_per_10_min': 1.0}, {'wl_observed_m': None, 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'wl_forecasted_m': None, u'id': 6, 'rainfall_mm_per_10_min': None}]
```

Converting to json

```
In [19]: all = DataForecast.objects.all().values()

In [20]: all
Out[20]: [{'wl_observed_m': 2.0, 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 27, 6, 5, 36, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'wl_forecasted_m': 2.0, u'id': 5, 'rainfall_mm_per_10_min': 1.0}, {'wl_observed_m': None, 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'wl_forecasted_m': None, u'id': 6, 'rainfall_mm_per_10_min': None}]

In [21]: for i in all: i['date_time'] =  i['date_time'].strftime("%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S")

In [22]: all
Out[22]: [{'wl_observed_m': 2.0, 'date_time': 'Mar 27 2015 06:05:36', 'wl_forecasted_m': 2.0, u'id': 5, 'rainfall_mm_per_10_min': 1.0}, {'wl_observed_m': None, 'date_time': 'Jan 01 2001 00:00:00', 'wl_forecasted_m': None, u'id': 6, 'rainfall_mm_per_10_min': None}]

In [23]: import json

In [25]: json.dumps(list(all))                                                                                                                                                  
Out[25]: '[{"wl_observed_m": 2.0, "date_time": "Mar 27 2015 06:05:36", "wl_forecasted_m": 2.0, "id": 5, "rainfall_mm_per_10_min": 1.0}, {"wl_observed_m": null, "date_time": "Jan 01 2001 00:00:00", "wl_forecasted_m": null, "id": 6, "rainfall_mm_per_10_min": null}]'
```

Comment: It returns `"date_time": "2014-01-18T14:00:00"`,  but I wanted it to be formatted like `Jan 18, 2014 02:00 PM`

Comment: you convert it using `strftime` like `value.strftime("%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S")`, or if you want to show it in template you can use `date`  like `{{ value|date:"D d M Y" }}`

Comment: How do I do that? I'm passing a JSON data in my template.

Comment: @SachiTekina  updated answer, looks like json dumps is working